# Linq to sql into object list

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Please consider following tables:

### TblDocument

```
docID,  levelID, name 
101,    201,     AAA 
102,    201,     BBB 
103,    201,     CCC 
104,    202,     DDD 
105,    202,     EEE
```

### TblPage

```
pgID, docID, pgNo
1,    101,   1
2,    102,   1
3,    102,   2
4,    103,   1
5,    104,   1
6,    105,   1
```

### TblFieldName

```
fieldNameID, levelID, fieldName  
1,           201,     WrittenBy  
2,           201,     VerifiedBy 
3,           201,     DocumentName
```

### TblFieldValue

```
docID,  fieldNameID, fieldValue 
101,    1,           James 
101,    2,           Bond  
101,    3,           Essay on something  
102,    1,           Krister
102,    2,           Holm
102,    3,           Dame it or not!
```

---

```
public class Document
{
  public int DocID {get; set;}
  public int LevelID {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}

  public List<Field> Metadata
  {
     get { return (_fields); }
     set { _fields = value; }
  }       
  private List<Field> _fields = new List<Field>();
}


public class Field
    {
      public FieldNameID {get; set;}
      public FieldName {get; set;}
      public FieldValue {get; set;}
    }
```

Now, I am trying to fetch data from database using linq that works fine.

```
using (DBDataContext context = new DBDataContext())
{
  List<Document> doc  = (from d in context.TblDocuments
     join p in context.TblPages on d.docID equals p.docID into dpgrp
     from dp in dpgrp.Where(f => f.docID == d.docID).DefaultIfEmpty()
     where d.levelID == 201
     select new Document
     {
       DocumentID = d.docID,
       LevelID = d.levID
     }).ToList<Document>();
 }
```

Can someone help me how can I get field values in a list?

```
using (DBDataContext context = new DBDataContext())
{
  List<Document> doc  = (from d in context.TblDocuments
     join p in context.TblPages on d.docID equals p.docID into dpgrp
     from dp in dpgrp.Where(f => f.docID == d.docID).DefaultIfEmpty()
     where d.levID == 201
     select new Document
     {
       DocumentID = d.docID,
       LevelID = d.levID
       Metadata = ???????            // how to achieve this? as it is a list
     }).ToList<Document>();
 }
```

Comment: What's wrong with `d.something` being a list? If you don't want the entire list and just the values from the `Field`s, then you can use a subquery.

Comment: @GrantThomas: How? Could you write a sample query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use `DataLoadOptions` for L2S

```
options.LoadWith<Document>(d => d.Metadata);
```

Comment: I never knew LoadWith() makes things much easier. Thanks.